# degree symbol for labels in R is messed up

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, ubuntu-20.04

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. When I use ggplot2 to plot some geographical data, I discover that the degree symbol in the axis labels is messed up (I attached a snip). Does anyone have a solution for that? The same thing occurs if I use a different plotting library (e.g.lattice). I can provide some reproducible code as well although this is not exactly an error to reproduce.[image].

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a workaround e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60733863/12957340 ? Otherwise, please post the code that led to this problem and/or a minimal reproducible example to help troubleshoot

Comment: You need the cairo device to render pdf images with non ASCII unicode characters (like teh degree symbol)

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks a lot, I will try this for now.