# degree symbol incorrect in ggplot map axis labels on Windows 10

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is very similar to [r - degree symbol incorrect in map axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467046/degree-symbol-incorrect-in-map-axis-labels), though that was on a Linux machine. I'm experiencing a similar issue on Windows 10.

```
library(sf)                                            
library(ggplot2) 
                                      
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

ggplot() +                                             
  geom_sf(data = nc)
```

Produces the following:
[image: v]

I expect the degree symbols to render properly, and suspect this has something to do with Windoze fonts. However, I'm not sure how best to address the matter.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467046/degree-symbol-incorrect-in-map-axis-labels) to the other question involves editing a `/etc/fonts/local.conf` file. I find several of these files on the system, one of them is in the R directory but for an older version of R. I'm a bit weary of editing random config files without understanding what I'm doing. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is and example is ad seq in xlab and ylabs

```
perurna = rnaturalearth::ne_countries(country = 'PERU',returnclass = 'sf')
perurna

xlabs = seq(-81,-68, 2)
ylabs = seq(-18, -0,3)
perurna

  ggplot(data =et1)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Longitud, y = Latitud,color=value),size=2) +
  geom_sf(fill='transparent',data=perurna, colour = "transparent")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = xlabs, labels = paste0(xlabs,'°W')) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = ylabs, labels = paste0(ylabs,'°S')) +
  geom_polygon(data=shp2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color = "black",fill=NA, size = .1)+
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(5),breaks=seq(-1,1,0.2),limits=c(-1,1))+
  geom_point(aes(x = Longitud, y = Latitud),colour = "black",alpha = 0.3,shape=21,size=2) +
  labs(x = "LON",y= "LAT",color = "PP CORR")+
  theme_cowplot()+
  ggtitle("Correlacion Precipitacion") + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color='black',linetype = 'dashed',size = 0.1),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.ontop = TRUE,
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA,color='black'),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).